# How to remove the click event of the progress bar in video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

The project I'm working on doesn't want to change the video schedule when I click on the progress bar, so I want to drop the click event of the progress bar.

Comment: Which plugin do you use to play video? Based on that you can get the solution

Comment: Why not turn off the controls altogether? @rushil It's mentioned in the title, and the question is tagged with video.js.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I missed that and just read the question content. Of course you can disable all controls. Just need to check if they do disable pause/play buttons or not as they might be needed

Comment: I just want to get rid of the click event of the progress bar, because I need to show the progress bar. I think videojs should have a similar solution, but unfortunately I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

For videojs I found this [one](https://github.com/rsadwick/videojs-disable-progress). Check the fiddle at the end of the github page.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not what I want, it's very similar, but I still need to keep dragging when removing clicks. Maybe I need to write it myself.